# Insert Image to asp.net Page

Tags: asp.net

I just want to insert a picture into a asp.net page and this is how I proceeded ...
in the project i created an image folder and inserted the image there. in the html I use the img tag and enter the path to the image as src. In the browser I see that there should be a picture but it is not displayed. not even with the absolute path

Folder Structure....
[image]

```
<img src="\Images\file_example_PNG_500kB.png" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Images` folder inside the `wwwroot` folder - that's where all static files are served from.

You should then be able to use an app-relative URL for the image:

```html
<img src="~/Images/file_example_PNG_500kB.png" />
```

Comment: thanx, works perfect

Comment: '~' / tilde represents the Application root (wwwroot)